# How do you explicitly find a record where a field is NULL?

Tags: go, go-gorm

From the [documentation](http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map):

> When query with struct, GORM will only query with those fields has non-zero value, that means if your field’s value is 0, '', false or other zero values, it won’t be used to build query conditions.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do :

```
type Dog struct {
  ID uuid.UUID
  OwnerID *uuid.UUID
}
```

The owner ID pointer may be nil.

```
db.Where("owner_id", nil).Find(&dogs)
```

But that returns all dogs (I expected this from the doc). I tried doing:

```
db.Where("owner_id", "NULL").Find(&dogs)
```

But that returns an empty list.

Is there a way to explicitly search for a `NULL` value field?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the docs, this should work:

```
db.Where("owner_id IS NULL").Find(&dogs)
```

Comment: where is the docs link sir?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you want to get the data with the value is null. You only have some choices.

1. use map interface
2. use struct with conditions

```golang
db.Where("owner_id IS NULL").Find(&dogs)
// or you can also try different way of writing
db.Find(&dogs, "owner_id IS NULL")
```

Answer (score -2):

You were close in your original attempt. You can also achieve your desired result by writing the query as below.

```
db.Where("owner_id = ?", "NULL").Find(&dogs)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: because NULL here is a string